# В MySQL дата записывается на 3 часа меньше - как выправить?

Tags: javascript, mysql, дата

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дата записывается на 3 часа меньше. И, соответственно, потом получается из базы также. Как это поправить? Часовой пояс Москвы.

Код JS записи:

````
this.$root.end_at = new Date();
this.$root.end_at.setTime(this.$root.end_at.getTime() + (this.test_info[0].time_limit * 60 * 1000));
this.$root.end_at = this.$root.end_at.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объект даты созданный через `new Date()` в `JS` при вызове метода `.toISOString()` вернет строку в `UTC`, если вы хотите сохранить ее с таймзоной браузера клиента, то стоит использовать метод `.toLocaleString()`. Хотя в принципе все эти подходы являются не верными, хотя вопрос и холиварный но опыт подсказывает, что датами должен управлять сервер, если только эти даты не вводит сам человек, гораздо проще общий UTC timestamp на клиентах привести к локальному времени клиента, чем потом разбираться в мешанине времени в базе.

Answer (score 0):

Сам так сделал в итоге:

```
this.$root.end_at = new Date();
this.$root.end_at.setTime(this.$root.end_at.getTime() - (this.$root.end_at.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000) + (15 * 60 * 1000)); // this.test_info[0].time_limit
this.$root.end_at = this.$root.end_at.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод `toISOString` возвращает дату в нормальным формате с указанием часового пояса UTC.

Просто не надо над ней издеваться, что-то из неё вырезать и заменять буквы. Короче, убери вот это: `.slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')`.

Comment: Нет, так не работает.